# Why is this wrong? (C# Task ContinueWith)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

When I write the following code:

```
 Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => "first task")
         .ContinueWith(t =>
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
                     Console.WriteLine("second task");
                 });
```

That is wrong!

Then I change it to this:

```
 var  task = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => "first task")
         .ContinueWith(t =>
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
                     Console.WriteLine("second task");
                 });
```

Then everything is OK!

Why?

What is the different between "Task task"  and "var task"？

Comment: What do you mean by wrong, and ok?

Comment: Most likely compiler error, considering `ContinueWith` doesn't return a `Task<string>`. But it would help if the OP stated this already. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your line of code returns a `Task`, not a `Task<string>` object, because you wrote `ContinueWith`, not `ContinueWith<string>`.

A tip that could help you in the future: when you replace a type by `var` in a variable declaration, you can move your mouse over the `var` keyword in Visual Studio, a pop-up will be shown with the actual type the `var` *hides* in your code.

Comment: +1 twice if I could, for pointing out not to simply use `var` as a fire-and-forget device.

Answer (score 2):

`task` is a reference to the continuation and not the original task (a reference to the original task is passed as `t` to the continuation).

Since the continuation doesn't return anything its not a `Task<string>`. Obviously `var` handles this which is why your second example works and the first doesn't.